# Spring MVC3 didn't need DispatcherServlet in web.xml also can work?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I read a project which use spring mvc3, I find that there's not a DispatcherServlet config in web.xml, also didn't has a ContextLoaderListener, even didn't specify the spring config xml file, but it can work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 3.1 Version Spring is allowing xml free configuration even for servlet environment. That is why you didn't see any xml files in that project.

Refer to below reference for more details:

[spring ref](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/)

[another ref](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/spring-mvc-configuration-without-xml/)